# Async request in library which support AMD

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, requirejs, amd

I have a problem with a library I want to build because of async request I made with XMLHttpRequest. I will explain with some code :

```
(function(root,factory){
    if( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ){
        // AMD module
        define([], factory);
    }else{
        global.tof = factory();
    }
})(this, () => {
    const obj = {
        datas: {},
        get: function(){}
        ...
    }
    const url = "...";
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET',url);
    request.responseType = 'json';
    request.send();
    request.onload= function(){
        obj.datas = request.response;
    }
    return obj;
});
```

I worked with callback to be sure I receive data and define my module when data has loaded but when I load the "library" with requireJS it still fires before my module is really defined.

```
(function(root,factory){

    function myCallback(r){

        if( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ){
            // AMD module
            define('tof',[], factory(function(r){
                return r;
            }));
        }
    }
    factory(myCallback);

})(this, function foo(callback){
    const obj = {
        datas: {},
        get: function(){}
        ...
    }
    const url = "...";
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET',url);
    request.responseType = 'json';
    request.send();
    request.onload= function(){
        obj.datas = request.response;
        callback(obj);
    }
});
```

My other script I used to test my module with requireJS :

```
require(['tof'], function(tof){
    // return undefined because of my async request
    console.log(tof);
});
```

How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you quickly figured out your 1st attempt cannot work, since you cannot use a synchronous `return` to return a value obtained asynchronously.

Your 2nd attempt cannot work either. It looks like you'd like the factory function you pass to `define` to *define a module asynchronously* but RequireJS does not allow that. What you need to do is design your module in a way that it provides a function that allows the user of the module to retrieve the result of the `XMLHTTPRequest` asynchronously.

Here's a sketch of some possibility. I emphasize that this is a *sketch*. I typed this off-the-cuff. At the very least, you'll need to add error handling code:

```
define(function () {
    const promise =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET',url);
        request.responseType = 'json';
        request.send();
        request.onload = () => {
            obj.datas = request.response;
            resolve(obj);
        };
    });

    return {
        getResult: () => promise,
    };
});
```

Then you'd use it elsewhere like:

```
require(['tof'], function (tof) {
    tof.getResult().then((result) => console.log(result));
});
```